# Как включить подсказки для пути картинки?

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите , как в vue сделать так , чтобы когда я пишу путь к картинке , у меня выпадала папки где может располагаться картинка ? Пробовал в вуе конфиг засунуть plugins, но ничего не вышло

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
  publicPath: '.',
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

Comment: Вы про кодовый редактор?

Comment: Хотел бы , чтобы было вот так , когда я пишу путь к картинке https://imgur.com/a/yZ1rvKp